# C# NancyFx trying to find accept headers

Tags: c#, nancy, request-headers

I have this function to determine what to render on the page when an error occurs (404/500):

```
    private enum RenderType
    {
       HTML,
       Json,
       Text
    }

    private RenderType GetRenderType(NancyContext context)
    {
        var enumerable = context.Request.Headers.Accept;
        var ranges = enumerable.OrderByDescending(o => o.Item2).Select(o => new MediaRange(o.Item1)).ToList();

        foreach (var item in ranges)
        {
            if (item.Matches("text/html")) 
            { 
                return RenderType.HTML;
            }
            else if (item.Matches("application/json") || item.Matches("text/json"))
            {
                return RenderType.Json;
            }
        }

        return RenderType.Text;
    }
```

The problem is that it returns the first RenderType to go through the if statement, if its an unknown accept header. I changed around the code, it defaults to the first if statement not RenderType.Text.

I've been up all night trying to figure this one out. Anyone got any idea what could be doing this?

On I side note, I know the what is being sent, this is from the chrome debugger:

```
Sent: 
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8

Recieved:
Status Code:404 Not Found
Content-Type:text/html
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

As you can see it's returning html not text, the Content-Type header should be "text/plain"

Comment: Did you figure it out yet?

Comment: Not yet, I have no idea why it's doing that.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `*/*`? I suspect that is the first in the collection.